# Can I use a simple path for an area chart's legend item symbol?

Tags: highcharts

When markers are disabled, the symbols used for a line chart are simple vertically-centered paths

[image]

but for area charts are rectangles

[image]

I'd like to use the paths for all chart types, and I can't figure out how. The closest I've gotten is to set `legend.symbolHeight` to `2`, but this results in a bottom-aligned rectangle for the area chart:

[image]

Is it possible to tell all charts to use the vertically-centered path?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a fake series with different type and then [linked](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.linkedTo) two series by the option.

```
    series: [{
          type: 'line',
          data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
        }, {
          type: 'line',
          data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
        },{
            type: 'line',
          color: 'red',
        }, {
          color: 'red',
          type: 'area',
          showInLegend: false,
          linkedTo:':previous',
          data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
   }]
```

Example:
 - http://jsfiddle.net/kjq0cn8p/